# have a conflicting types error

Tags: c, compiler-errors

when compiling my c file i get this error
i can't seem to get my types correct for this program, how would I go about fixing this problem
I put up my .h file as well as my .c file

error

```
example4.c:35: error: conflicting types for ‘h’
example4.h:8: error: previous declaration of ‘h’ was here
```

example4.h code

```
typedef struct{
        int x;
        char s[10];
}Record;

void f(Record *r);
void g(Record r);
void h(const Record r);
```

example4.c code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "example4.h"

int main()
{
        Record value , *ptr;

        ptr = &value;

        value.x = 1;
        strcpy(value.s, "XYZ");

        f(ptr);
        printf("\nValue of x %d", ptr -> x);
        printf("\nValue of s %s", ptr->s);


        return 0;
}

void f(Record *r)
{
        r->x *= 10;
        (*r).s[0] = 'A';
}

void g(Record r)
{
        r.x *= 100;
        r.s[0] = 'B';
}

void h(Record *r)
{
        r->x *= 1000;
        r->s[0] = 'C';
}
```

Comment: See [Error: assignment of read-only location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226313/error-assignment-of-read-only-location) for the prequel to this question.

Comment: "how would I go about fixing this problem" -- By making the types the same, obviously. Did you even look at your code before posting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your header file declares `void h(const Record r);`

while your source file declares `void h(Record *r)`

You fixed the source file, but forgot to fix your header, when you were trying to apply the [answer I gave you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226313/error-assignment-of-read-only-location/16226326#16226326) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226313/error-assignment-of-read-only-location).